# junit spring boot parametrised test not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I have a basic test set up with paramters

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("intsTest")
public void multiplesOf5(Integer input){
    int i =0;
}

private static Stream<Arguments> intsTest(){
    Stream<Arguments> argumentsStream = Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(1));

    return argumentsStream;
}
```

But i cant seem to run it, i keep getting the following:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateExtensionContext does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExecutableInvoker getExecutableInvoker()' of interface org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodArgumentsProvider.lambda$provideArguments$2(MethodArgumentsProvider.java:60)
    )
```

my gradle has

```
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2")
```

Answer (score 1):

So I tried your code locally, the error came from the line

```
@MethodSource("intsTest")
```

In fact, by testing your method in the following way everything works:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
public void multiplesOf5(Integer input){
    int i = 0;
}
```

Now I solved the problem by fixing the dependencies in my pom.xml leaving only this one for JUnit:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I don't want to say inaccuracies but I hypothesize that having too many Junit dependencies perhaps leads to some conflict problems between them.

Comment: `junit-jupiter` is an "aggregator" jar. You don't need to also have the `junit-jupiter-engine` jar.

Comment: @Mureinik Thanks, I'll correct my answer then